# Problema con arrays, indice excedido c#

Tags: c#, array, .net, api

Dispongo de una clase que obtiene datos de una `API`, pasaré a explicar todo el código porque realmente no sé dónde está el problema.

```
 public static void Obtener_Enemigos()
        {
            RiotSharp.RiotApi Api = RiotApi.GetDevelopmentInstance(_Key);
            RiotSharp.StaticRiotApi StaticApi = StaticRiotApi.GetInstance(_Key);

            try
            {
                RiotSharp.SummonerEndpoint.Summoner Summoner = Api.GetSummonerByName(_Region, _NombreInvocador);
                List<RiotSharp.SpectatorEndpoint.Participant> Participants = Api.GetCurrentGame(_Region, Summoner.Id).Participants;

                // --- ## Diccionarios para cargar los campeones & hechizos ## --- //

                Dictionary<string, RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.Champion.ChampionStatic>.ValueCollection championlist =
                        StaticApi.GetChampions(_Region, RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.ChampionData.All).Champions.Values;

                Dictionary<string, RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.SummonerSpell.SummonerSpellStatic>.ValueCollection SummonerSpell =
                        StaticApi.GetSummonerSpells(_Region, RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.SummonerSpellData.All).SummonerSpells.Values;

                // --- ## Diccionarios para cargar los campeones & hechizos ## --- //

                int total = Participants.Count; // 10 Jugadores, 6 jugadores, X jugadores.
                int index = Participants.FindIndex(a => a.SummonerName == _NombreInvocador);

                enemigos = new string[total / 2, 3];

                if (index > (total / 2) - 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= (total / 2) - 1; i++)
                    {

                        IEnumerable<RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.Champion.ChampionStatic>
                        CampeonWhere = championlist.Where(yourself => yourself.Id == Participants[i].ChampionId);

                        IEnumerable<RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.SummonerSpell.SummonerSpellStatic>
                        Spell1Where = SummonerSpell.Where(yourself => yourself.Id == Participants[i].SummonerSpell1);

                        IEnumerable<RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.SummonerSpell.SummonerSpellStatic>
                        Spell2Where = SummonerSpell.Where(yourself => yourself.Id == Participants[i].SummonerSpell2);

                        enemigos[i, 0] = CampeonWhere.First().Name;
                        enemigos[i, 1] = Spell1Where.First().Name;
                        enemigos[i, 2] = Spell2Where.First().Name;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= (total / 2) - 1; i++)
                    {

                        IEnumerable<RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.Champion.ChampionStatic>
                        CampeonWhere = championlist.Where(yourself => yourself.Id == Participants[total / 2 + i].ChampionId);

                        IEnumerable<RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.SummonerSpell.SummonerSpellStatic>
                        Spell1Where = SummonerSpell.Where(yourself => yourself.Id == Participants[total / 2 + i].SummonerSpell1);

                        IEnumerable<RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.SummonerSpell.SummonerSpellStatic>
                        Spell2Where = SummonerSpell.Where(yourself => yourself.Id == Participants[total / 2 + i].SummonerSpell2);

                        enemigos[i, 0] = CampeonWhere.First().Name;
                        enemigos[i, 1] = Spell1Where.First().Name;
                        enemigos[i, 2] = Spell2Where.First().Name;

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (RiotSharpException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No funca tio");
            }
        }
```

En el juego, `el máximo de jugadores es 10`, 5 rivales 5 aliados, el mínimo son 2. (1 rival, 1 aliado). Le paso la `Key` que proporciona la Api (La key es un campo privado, que anteriormente debio ser rellenado, este metodo no se puede invocar sin que los campos `_Key`, `_Region` y _`NombreInvocador` estén vacios.) y a partir de ahí genero una `lista` con los `participantes` que están en juego.

Estos pueden ser `X`, si fuesen `10`, los `cinco primeros` pertenecen a un equipo, y los `cinco restantes` a otro. Si fuesen `8`, los `cuatro primeros` pertenecen a un equipo y los `cuatro restantes` a otro.

Teniendo esto en cuenta, como quiero saber unicamente el equipo enemigo, he de preguntarme en que posición se encuentra la persona buscada. (El jugador principal, digamos que yo). Si estoy en una posición menor que `(NumeroJugadoresTotales/2)-1`, significa que el equipo enemigo esta a partir de la segunda mitad. Por ejemplo, si hay 10 jugadores, y la posición del jugador principal es el número 6, significa que los enemigos estan desde el `0` hasta el `4`, porque sabemos que son cogidos de `5 en 5`. (Como mencione antes)

Sabiendo esto, y sabiendo en que posicion está el equipo rival, recorro un array multidimensional, (y la longitud de este, varia en funcion del numero de personas totales) Si hay 10 personas jugando, significa que solo necesitaré la mitad (los enemigos).

Cada enemigo tiene dos hechizos base, por eso el array multidimensional tiene una `costante de 2`.

Ahora, cargo los diccionarios de los personajes que existen, y los hechizos que existen, como el método devuelve el `ID`en `long`, lo que hago es preguntar dentro del diccionario a que string corresponde ese long.

Imaginemos que el nombre del personaje jugado sería `Sharki`, y el `id` es `8`. Con el método `GetChampions` obtendria el `id`, y con dicho `id` preguntaria en el diccionario anteriormente cargado a que `string` corresponde, teniendo como resultado `Sharki`.

De forma que tenemos un array multidimensional algo tal que así.

- NombrePersonaje1 [0 , 0]

  - HechizoPersonaje1 [0, 1]
  - HechizoPersonaje2 [0, 2]
- NombrePersonaje2 [1, 0]

  - HechizoPersonaje1 [1, 1]
  - HechizoPersonaje2 [1, 2]

Etc...

Como es un método `void`, y este método se ejecuta en el `form2_load`, esto cargará el campo `enemigos[,]` con los datos, para más tarde trabajar desde alli.

Hasta aquí todo bien, ahora viene el problema (y el que, según mi cabeza, no ve dónde está).

Quiero cargar una imagen de cada personaje con su respectivo hechizo, así que monto un `array` de `pictureboxs`.

```
PictureBox[,] imagen = new PictureBox[SharkiQuerys.enemigos.Length / 3, 2 ];

            imagen[0,0] = Invocador1;
            imagen[0,1] = Inv1Spell1;
            imagen[0,2] = Inv1Spell2;

            imagen[1,0] = Invocador2;
            imagen[1,1] = Inv2Spell1;
            imagen[1,2] = Inv2Spell2;

            imagen[2,0] = Invocador3;
            imagen[2,1] = Inv3Spell1;
            imagen[2,2] = Inv3Spell2;

            imagen[3,0] = Invocador4;
            imagen[3,1] = Inv4Spell1;
            imagen[3,2] = Inv4Spell2;

            imagen[4,0] = Invocador5;
            imagen[4,1] = Inv5Spell1;
            imagen[4,2] = Inv5Spell2;


            for (int i = 0; i <= SharkiQuerys.enemigos.Length / 3 ; i++)
            {
                imagen[i,0].ImageLocation =  "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/"      + SharkiQuerys.enemigos[i, 0] + ".png";
                imagen[i,1].ImageLocation =  "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/spell/Summoner" + SharkiQuerys.enemigos[i, 1] + ".png";
                imagen[i,2].ImageLocation =  "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/spell/Summoner" + SharkiQuerys.enemigos[i, 2] + ".png";

            }
```

Dado que el array no posee la propiedad `count`, utilizo la propiedad `lenght` que me devuelve el numero de elementos totales, en este caso, y para este ejemplo son quince. Ya que la matriz es de `5x3` y eso es un total de `15` elementos.

Como necesito trabajar con una matriz igual y sé que la constante siempre es 3. (Nombre, + hechizo + hechizo 2) a la longitud la divido entre 3, y sigo con la constante de tres tal que el array queda con `[Longitud/3, 3]` (recordemos que la longitud variara dependiendo de si son 10 jugadoresm 6, X...)

Ahora lo unico que necesito es recorrer un for que recorra cada picture box hasta rellenar el numero total de jugadores, con sus respectivos hechizos.

Y he aqui el problema al ejecutar el programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El indice es excedido, pero la matriz es correcta, he probado a hacerlo con constantes en el array, de forma que la matriz fuese `[5, 3]` pero aun con esas, el error salta ahí.

Haciendo debuggin (lo poco que sé al respecto) ni si quiera llega al for, devuelve error en esa posición de la matriz y no sé el por qué.

Sería de mucha ayuda si alguien pudiese guiarme, espero haber explicado todo con claridad, si necesitáis más información pedirmela, gracias.

---

Edito: Me siento tonto, el problema es que declare un array con una constante de 2, cuándo es de 3. Por eso lanza la excepción...

Igualmente, soy consciente de que el código se podría optimizar mucho más, si alguien tuviese el tiempo necesario de explicarme que cosas estoy haciendo mal, se lo agradeceria.

Comment: me fije en mi compilador.. porque el problema es trivial.. fijate que estas definiendo la matriz como [5,2].. eso quiere decir que tu matriz tiene los elementos [0,0] [0,1] [1,0].. pero el elemento [0,2] no existe.. porque muestra el error en la linea siguiente, no lo se, pero el problema es ese.

Comment: @gbianchi Exacto, justamente acabo de darme cuenta de eso, estaba tan centrado que la linea que resaltaba no tenía ningún problema que no me di cuenta de que la excepción la generaba porque la matriz estaba con constante de 2 y no de 3... Ahora funciona perfectamente! Gracias :P

Comment: +1 por `Console.WriteLine("No funca tio");`.

Comment: JAJAJAA olvidé editarlo, que verguenza @Xam